# three two-form of total differential

Tags: tensor-products, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

I am doing an exercise about tensor product.

Let $\alpha$ = $3dx+2dy+dz$ and $\beta$ = $2dx++2dy-2dz$.

What are the two-forms $\alpha \otimes \beta$, $\alpha\beta$ and $\alpha \wedge \beta$? Also, is any of them non-degenerate?

I'm stuck that I just know how to do this in matrix form. Any ideas?

Comment: These products are bilinear, so for instance $(a+b)\otimes (c+d) = a\otimes c + a \otimes d + b \otimes c + b \otimes d$ and similarly for the others.

Comment: What is the definition of $\alpha\beta$?

Comment: I think $\alpha \beta$ is probably the symmetrization of $\alpha \otimes \beta$ (the projection onto the symmetric tensors)